What would a finite statement machine look like that only accepts strings that start and end with 1?
Construct an FSM that accepts a binary string that must start with and end with 1.
Examples: 1111011, 1, 1001001, 11001, 101010101
^^^This is the question, and I am beyond confused of what the diagram would look like.
I quite literally had no idea what I was doing. I put this but I feel like it's very wrong...bad answer
